# ASP Disable - enable foreign key datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, constraints

Well, I'm working in an ASP project with C#. I have two datatables in a database, let's say table A and table B.

Table B has a foreign key constraint on its column B wich is related with column A on table A.

I want to update column A on table A programatically but foreign key fires on table B. So the question is: How can I disable the foreign key on table B, then update data on column A table A and then re-enable the foreign key programatically?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The foreign key must be unique.  The only reason you would get an error is if you are adding duplicate keys.  Using UPDATE (not INSERT) will allow an entry with the same key to be changed.  The other choice would be to remove the row with the duplicate key before INSERTING the key.

Comment: Thanks for answer jdweng. OK, column A on table A is unique, but when I try to update its value programatically, I get this sqlException: "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CONSTRAINT". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE.MDF", table "dbo.B", column 'B'.". That's why I need to disable its foreign key with column A on table A before updating.

Comment: The database is a two dimension object with rows and columns.  The database has views which groups the columns into separate tables for efficiency.  The keys are columns in the database that require values.  Your error is occurring because you are adding a row to the database but not filling in all the keys in the row at one time.  The solution is to INSERT a row to the database with all the keys.  You don't have to add just one table/view at a time.

Comment: Sorry jdweng, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. I don't want to INSERT new rows, but UPDATE two existing ones, one in table A and the other one in table B, both related each other by a foreign key that don't let apply the changes. Thanks again.

Comment: Update should not give an error if you aren't changing a key.  When you have more than one key in a database the multiple keys become a group.  The group has to be unique and none of the keys can be null.  So when you create (with INSERT) a new group of keys you have to make sure the group is unique.  When UPDATE you have to make sure all keys exist.  You may have to change the order (or break the update to multiple commands to server) to make sure you don't violate foreign key restraints.  The two tables are part of the same row in the database that is defined by the group of keys.